# mysql group by any one or more of several fields

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I am looking to group by the following criteria:

so lets say I have how can I group them all 
    product1,brand1,null,null,12,null,1234

```
product2,brand1,null,null,12,null,null

product3,brand2,null,null,null,1234

product1,brand1,null,null,null,null,null


(product_name AND brand_name) upc or isbn or mpn or ean or model_number
```

is it possible to create a single select statement to return these grouped values ?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Give a fuller SQL statement so its clear what clause you're trying to put that in.

Comment: I am trying to:

    SELECT * from products group by (product_name, brand_name) or upc or isbn or mpn or ean or model_number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is "No."  How would MySQL know which one you want to group by in a particular situation?  It wouldn't.  You need to send MySQL a different SQL query for each situation.

If in your UI the user chose to group by one thing, send MySQL a query to group by that.  If they chose to group by something else, send MySQL a query to group by that.  You have to choose in PHP before you tell MySQL what to do.  You can't expect MySQL to read your mind and know "in this case he wants to group by X."

You can, however, group by all those fields, giving them a priority.  I.e. group by this one first, then by that one, etc.  Like:

```
SELECT * from products 
group by 
product_name, brand_name,
upc, isbn, mpn, ean, model_number
```

But this is not going to group by one or the other. It will group by all of them, giving first priority to the first mentioned.

Comment: I currently use a nested query which works well but I get duplicate results which i have to check against making 3 mysql queries per product group to achieve my goal can you think of a better way?

Comment: @Adrian Brown. `select distinct` perhaps.